# Extracting objects of two different classes from a .txt file into their associated ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, filereader

I have been asked to create a programme for a librarian as part of a task. There are two classes: User and Book.

User class is made up of fields: first-name, last-name and the number of books held.

Book class is made up of fields: title, authorNameOne and a boolean 'loan'.

One of the features of the programme is the ability for it read a .txt file and then convert different parts of the .txt into the appropriate objects. The text file is presented as:

```
5 
Concurrent Programming 
C. R. Snow 
Concurrent Programming 
Stephen J. Hartley 
Java Gently 
Judith Bishop 
Petri Nets 
Wolfgang Reisig 
Finite Transition Systems 
Andre Arnold 
4 
Anna Smith 
Zoe Brown
John Williams 
John Smith
```

The format goes:

the top number (5) illustrates the amount of books in the library.

Underneath this, the next 10 lines essentially represents the 5 Book objects ( I have created a secondary Book constructor in the Book class to facilitate this w just title and author- assumed this was the right procedure) e.g. Concurrent Programming C. R. Snow - makes up the title of the book with the authorName underneath.

The next number in the list (4) illustrates the amount of Users the library has.

Underneath this, the next 4 lines represent the 4 User objects (again this has required me to create a second User constructor with first-name and surname).

I have read these via

```
    File file = new File("/Users/jakehumphreys/IdeaProjects/cw2/src/library.txt");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
```

and then stored them in an ArrayList of class Object.

```
    ArrayList<Object> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    while(s.hasNextLine()){
        lines.add(s.nextLine());
    }

    System.out.println(lines);
```

This is the output (as expected):

```
[5, Concurrent Programming, C.R.Snow, Concurrent Programming, Stephen J.Hartley, Java Gently, Judith Bishop, Petri Nets, Wolfgang Reisig, Finite TransitionSystems, Andre Arnold, 4, Anna Smith, Zoe Brown, John Williams, John Smith]
```

The issue that is perplexing me is:

How do I get the scanner (or an appropriate filereader) to dissect the List accordingly i.e. so only the 5 pairs of lines under the number of books are bundled together to create the 5 book objects - which will then be added to ArrayList (that I have already created).

This applies similarly  to the 4 user objects below - they will ultimately need to end up in the ArrayList.

One thought I had was that the ints / numbers in the .txt list are clearly there as dividers, so maybe I could construct a while loop for the filereader in order to get it to read the books appropriately etc.

Or Do I need to partition the ArrayList instead after i have read the .txt file

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank-you in advance : ).

Comment: This is not a homework-writing service. A better design would be to have two files, one for users and one for books. And neither of them should have the number of items. You should be using ArrayLists or other Collections framework classes rather than arrays.

Comment: There's really no need to read the raw data into an `ArrayList` and partition it up later.  As you say, the text file has a structure to it, and you can build your program to take advantage of that.

Comment: Given the file format that you have, use a for-loop to read the books into a books arraylist. Then use another for-loop to read the users into a second Users ArrayList.

Comment: @NomadMaker I understand it isn't, but it is also a help site, no? I thank you for the advice regardless - I will try the for loop suggestion : )

Comment: Yes, but we would need to see your entire code (or a working subset of the code) to help you with bugs. This is not a site for brainstorming and tutorials. I did notice that you did edit your question. One thing: I suggest never to make a List of Objects. Your User's should be a class (probably called User, though you could use String since you're only using the name). The books should be a class called Book.

Comment: @NomadMaker Ok thats cool, fair enough - this is my first post and I started a Com Sci conversion not long ago, so I feel like i'm relatively new to this + need as much help as I can acquire. In terms of what you just said regarding the classes, I have implemented that already, but like you say i haven't explicitly shown my other classes here . This code above is all happening in my main in my driver class. And because theres a mixture of objects 'to-be' within ther .txt file, i felt like an object array / string array would be best in order to then dissect into specific objects of user  etc

Comment: One thing is that you should not put Book's and User's in the same ArrayList.

Comment: @NomadMaker ok thats cool, that makes sense in terms of your for loop suggestion, thanks for the help again mate : )